# Creating an XML-based language with proper styling

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

For example, look at MathML or SVG.  These are not just XML-based languages, they are XML-based languages that you can embed directly into an HTML document, and they render perfectly.  You dont need namespaces or doctypes or XSL documents or stylesheets, or any of that other garbage for them to work properly (at least not in the latest Firefox).

I was curious, how might I make my own XML-based language that I can also embed directly into an HTML document?  How can I make it render exactly I wish, such as with proper styling, without having to embed the stylesheet into the document?

I was wondering how I can get my browser, firefox, to "know" the proper styling methods and formatting methods to an xml language that I create myself (obviously it would only properly render on my own machine).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is XSLT. You can write an XSLT stylesheet that runs in the browser to render the XML. All the browsers now support XSLT 1.0, and we (Saxonica) offer a cross-browser implementation of XSLT 2.0 called Saxon-CE, which is about to become open source.